# Transitive verbs

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

All over my neighborhood, there are local authority signs which read 'Remember to social distance' this strikes me as an odd expression and grammatically incorrect.  Is 'distance' in this sentence not a transitive verb in need of an object?

Comment: Please provide a couple of examples with an object.

Comment: A) "Distance", as a verb, is not transitive (in most uses, at least).  B) A transitive verb does not require an object, it simply allows one.

Comment: I think John expected to see "Remember to socially distance *yourselves*", @Xanne, instead of the back-formation that "practice social distancing" might suggest.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan I would like him to tell us what his problem is.

Comment: From my grammar books, I am told that transitive verbs require an object to make sense and intransitive verbs do not need an object.  Is this wrong?  'Remember to (socially) distance'  seems incomplete. How does one spot transitive and intransitive verbs?

Comment: This is a new idiom, don't try to interpret it literally. It means "keep social distance".

Comment: @JohnLawson That's basically true but many verbs can be used both transitively and intransitively. Think of "to run", we can say "I run every morning for my health" (intransitive) and we can say "I run marathons because I enjoy it" (transitive). Similarly with the verb "to think" we can say both "I think, therefore I am.!" and "Think happy thoughts".

Comment: @JohnLawson Also transitive verbs can have the object _implied_, the sentence "When I'm sad I think of home" seems to use "think" intransitively but is actually a shortened version of "When I'm sad I think _thoughts_ of home" and so is transitive with "thoughts of home" as the object.